# pass an array of objects in sling servlet

Tags: java, jquery, servlets, aem

I have an array of objects.

```
var mydata1 = {};
var mydata2={};
mydata1.name="john";
mydata2.class="third";
mydata2.name="pan";
mydata3.class="second";
var dataArray= new Array();
dataArray[0]=mydata1;
dataArray[1]=mydata2;

in ajax call
  jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/myservlet',
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataArray,
        async: false,
        success: function(result) {
            alert("Saved Node.")
        },
        failure:function(result) {
            alert("Not Saved")
        }
    });
```

Objects are required to be made because the value in objects is dynamic.And will change in future.How to pass this kind of object through ajax.
Can we change into JSON. But iteration in servlet is also required.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify()` function on the data array to serialize it to the JSON format:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/myservlet',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataArray),
    ...
```

Then you may read the JSON in the servlet using [JSONArray](http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling6/org/apache/sling/commons/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String requestData = request.getReader().readLine();
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(requestData);
// to get name property of the first object:
array.getJSONObject(0).getString("name");
```

Created JSON will be just a single line of text, so we don't need to read more lines from the request reader.

Comment: I am getting an error 405 when using the JSONArray Library, are there any ways to configure it or bypass it?